# mobile web - disable rotation

Tags: jquery-mobile, landscape-portrait

Hi im building an app for android phone with jquery mobile.

is there way to disable auto rotated screen on phone ?

i mean.. i want my mobile  website forced to portrait only....

Comment: it is surely not possible, its a mobile feature that browsers dnt support...

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975387/mobile-site-force-landscape-only-no-auto-rotate