# How to stop mobile screen rotaion using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create a html page using jQuery with rotation off in mobile. Its not working at my end.

Can you please give me any suggestion by which when I run this html page in mobile it shouldn't be rotate?

I have used following code :

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange resize', function(event){
   if (event.orientation) {
  if (event.orientation == 'landscape') {
    if (window.orientation == 90) {
   rotate(this, -90);
    } else {
   rotate(this, 90);
    }
  }
   }
 });

 function rotate(el, degs) {
   iedegs = degs/90;
   if (iedegs < 0) iedegs += 4;
   transform = 'rotate('+degs+'deg)';
   iefilter = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation='+iedegs+')';
   styles = {
  transform: transform,
  '-webkit-transform': transform,
  '-moz-transform': transform,
  '-o-transform': transform,
  filter: iefilter,
  '-ms-filter': iefilter
   };

   $(window).css(styles);
 };
```

Comment: Actually I am creating a page that must be shown in portrait

Comment: and what do you expect to happen when a user looks at it with a device that is naturally wider than tall? tablet, phone held sideways, etc?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10977420/3164682

Comment: Its dosen't look good. I want to it only portrait. when user try to move it in landscape position then it shouldn't be move

Comment: As per my knowledge, it doesn't works that way.! javascript/Jquery can't control the device orientation due to technology limitations. If it was an app, then its possible.!
But you  can try something like giving an alert message when user changes the orientation of the mobile.
For Example, check this banks mobile website.
http://m.axisbank.com

Answer (score 0):

In the second half of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360581/force-landscape-orientation-mode#14360699) answer there is a trick using a json setting (mainfest) file.

The short story: Create a `mainfest.json` file:

```
 {
     "display":      "standalone", /* Could be "fullscreen", "standalone", "minimal-ui", or "browser" */
     "orientation":  "landscape", /* Could be "landscape" or "portrait" */
     ...
 }
```

Then add to your HTML page:

```
 <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```