# Force horizontal screen on webpage Mobile

Tags: html, mobile, rotation

I made a website with bootstrap, But when the screen is vertical **on mobile** you don't see the whole text. So i want a code that make the screen horizontal  **on mobile**...
Is this posible?

Answer (score 0):

I never use bootstrap but **you need** just a code that could help you to render your web page vertically and horizontally.

First of all, if I need to write code for mobile then I would configure my elements with "%" dimensions.

After this, i will put this meta-tag into the head bar:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=0, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

This will help you to render your site on every width device (vertically and horizontally).
If you want to change something there, remember:

- user-scalable=0 -> no zoom enabled.
- initial-scale -> default zoom level.
- minimum-scale -> minimum zoom level allowed.
- maximum-scale -> maximum zoom level allowed.

Comment: Thats not where i'm searching for... I'm searching for a code that render a webpage in landscape mode on mobile devices

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand so. Do you need a code that force user to render your webpage only horizontally?

Comment: So you have to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975387/mobile-site-force-landscape-only-no-auto-rotate and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738072/forcing-web-site-to-show-in-landscape-mode-only ;)